# What do the Unplayed Paths mean in the remaster?

Tags: beyond-two-souls-remaster

Does somebody know where I can find all paths in Beyond Two Souls Remastered? 
I also have a question about the unplayed path in "The Mission" (with Salim). What is in unplayed path (marked blue) on the picture ?

> [image: paths image]

Comment: omg SPOILER alert!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the other path is labelled as `Unplayed Path` is because you haven't chosen to go down that path yet (in any playthrough). If you were to replay the game and make the opposite choices, you would see both choices rather than the choice you made and `Unplayed Path`. For [reference](http://www.playstationtrophies.org/forum/beyond-two-souls/213556-beyond-two-souls-trophy-guide-road-map-45.html):

> Another difference from what I can tell is that you can see what endings you're missing. After completing a chapter you get shown a choice or % path that other players taken. In this some paths are undiscovered.

To get all of the endings, [here](http://www.ign.com/wikis/beyond-two-souls/All_Endings...) is a guide.

**EDIT:**

I haven't been able to find any lists with the titles of the choices in each chapter, but on the [Beyond: Two Souls Chapters wikia](http://beyondtwosouls.wikia.com/wiki/Chapters), each chapter lists its possible endings.

If you want to see all 24 endings for the game itself, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IsGN34nE_fM) is a video with all the final cutscenes.

Per your comment about viewing them in the end mission screen without actually playing them, there is no way to do that. The entire point of them being marked as `Unplayed Paths` is because *you have not played them yet.*

Comment: Yes, but it is not full answer. I don't want to play some missions again. I just want to see other ways in end mission screen without playing again. So maybe someone have all path discovered ?
And in some cases we don't need to discover all paths for all endings. Especially in first missions.

Comment: I think the unplayed path in question is where you do try to commit suicide, just going from what I can see from that screenshot.

Comment: Does this apply to the original *Beyond: Two Souls*, or is this exclusive to the PS4 remaster?